# Python - Add OR Operator on DataFrame Apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I've this dataframe:

```
word, string1, string2
SQL, SQL is good, Programming
Java, Programming, Java is good
C#, Programming, Programming
```

I've a column that give a boolean if my column word values is present on my column string1:

```
data['res'] = data.apply(lambda x: x.word in x.string1
                               if (x.string1 == x.string1) and (x.word == x.word)
                               else False)
```

But what I want is to see if the column word value is present on column string1 OR in string2?
Something like this:

```
data['res'] = data.apply(lambda x: x.word in x.string1
                               if (x.string1 == x.string1) and (x.word == x.word)
                               else (x.word in x.string2
                                    if (x.string2 == x.string2) and (x.word == x.word))axis=1)
                    else False)
```

What I want is:

```
word, string1, string2, res
SQL, SQL is good, Programming, True
Java, Programming, Java is good, True
C#, Programming, Programming, False
```

Is this possible to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest is join both columns and add another filter:

```
data['res'] = data.apply(lambda x: x.word in x.string1 + x.string2
                               if (x.string1 == x.string1 ) and 
                                  (x.word == x.word) and 
                                  (x.string1 == x.string1)
                               else False, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the string in column 1 is present in any other columns, with [`any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) over axis=1:

```
df.apply(lambda x:x.str.contains(x.word),axis=1).iloc[:,1:].any(axis=1)
```

---

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
```

---

Full code:

```
df=df.assign(res=df.apply(lambda x:x.str.contains(x.word),axis=1).iloc[:,1:].any(axis=1))
```

---

```
   word       string1        string2    res
0   SQL   SQL is good    Programming   True
1  Java   Programming   Java is good   True
2    C#   Programming    Programming  False
```